# Executing PowerShell Script Inside WinForm

Tags: c#, winforms, powershell

I wanted to use a button on a WinForm to run a PowerShell script. When I run the program and click the button, nothing seems to happen.

```
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Windows.Forms;
using System.Management.Automation;
using System.Collections.ObjectModel;

namespace PowerShellWinForm
{
    public partial class frmMain : Form
   {
        public frmMain()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        private void btnExecutePS_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            HelloScript();
        }
        public void HelloScript()
        {
            using (PowerShell PowerShellInstance = PowerShell.Create())
            {
                PowerShellInstance.AddScript("[System.Windows.MessageBox]::Show('Hello')");
                PowerShellInstance.Invoke();
            }

        }
    }
}
```

What changes do I need to make to get it to display the message box through PowerShell?

Comment: Are you looking for `[System.Windows.Forms.MessageBox]::Show()`?

Comment: Yes that was it, thank you.